# Filtering arrays by strings

Tags: php, arrays

I have a situation where I have an array of path names, e.g

```
[0]: /var/www/mysite/fred.md
[1]: /var/www/mysite/george.md
[2]: /var/www/mysite/arthur.md
[3]: /var/www/mysite/.htaccess
```

I have another array of strings

```
[0]: fred
[1]: art
```

I want to filter the array of path names so that I end up with an array of items where any part of the path name matches the string - so I should get

```
[0]: /var/www/mysite/fred.md
[1]: /var/www/mysite/arthur.md
```

What's the most efficient way of doing this in PHP?

Comment: I think it would be a good idea if you tried something yourself before asking. Even a bit of research would be greatly appreciated. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have tried myself, looping through the first array and then looping through the second array, doing stristr matches on each item. It works, but I was looking for a more efficient method.

Comment: `$result = array_filter(
    $data,
    function($value) use ($matches) {
        return preg_match('/.*('.implode('|', $matches).').*/i', $value);
    }
);` - [Demo](https://3v4l.org/LcBfm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not more efficient than a loop but an alternate. As pointed out in the comments, a benefit is that you can use the strings as regular expressions:

```
$result = preg_grep('/'.implode('|', $strings).'/i', $pathnames);
```

To avoid characters in the strings being interpreted as a regular expression, escape them:

```
$pattern = implode("|", array_map(function($v){ return preg_quote($v, "/"); }, $strings));
$result  = preg_grep("/$pattern/i", $pathnames);
```

Comment: Thank you - works perfectly, and is much neater than my nested loops.

Comment: Keep in mind you're matching a regular expression, not just strings. For instance: A dot matches any one character, so searching for 'a.b' will match 'a.b' but also 'abb', 'aab' and 'acb'. Many more things like this can happen, do you know them all? Are you sure they won't occur in your application? In short: This is the worst solution if you want predictable and accurare results.

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient?

`array_filter` + your implementation of [KMP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).

But its only if you have large amounts of filtered data, if you need quick solution (but not stable and fast work for large amounts of data) use

`array_filter`, `strpos` and `substr` combinations, thay will work great for you, if speed not your priority.